# Insert multiple records at install time of plugin in nopcommerce

Tags: nopcommerce

I have custom table that is created by plugin.
I want to insert multiple record in my custom table at install time of plugin.

Can anyone tell me how can i do this?

Comment: May be you can do like, sleep thread and call your insertion script and insert dummy data.

Comment: no not like that i want to just insert multiple record in custom table when plugin installing

Comment: What do mean by *custom table*, you mean table which generate during installation of plugin ?

Comment: yes, exactly , custom table has been created by plugin.

Comment: Okay, then why you do not like to call custom script which include queries of  insertion of multiple record ? is there something preventing you?

Comment: okay, let me try that. Thank you Div

Comment: Okay, will let me know after if you find something not working, you're welcome aji :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, *custom table* means your table which is generated during installation of plugin.

You can create your script file *(Which include multiple data insertion queries)* and call this file after creating a plugin on Plugin install method.

Side Note: You may get an error if table will not create and you trying to run your script. So, you may need to use thread for that!, not sure.

Hope this helps!